# MongoDB Count total number of true and false values for documents matching a query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, nosql

Using the following data, how would I count the total number of yes and no votes for a collection of records with pollId "hr4946-113" using MongoDBs support for aggregate queries.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54abcdbeba070410146d6073"), "userId" : "1234", "pollId" : "hr4946-113", "vote" : true, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54afe32fec4444481b985711"), "userId" : "12345", "pollId" : "hr2840-113", "vote" : true, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54b66de68dde7a0c19be987b"), "userId" : "123456", "pollId" : "hr4946-113", "vote" : false }
```

This would be the expected Result.

```
{
   "yesCount": 1,
   "noCount":1
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) is your answer:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "pollId": "hr4946-113" } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$vote",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

Basically the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) operator gathers all the data by "key", and "grouping operators" like [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) work on the values. In this case, just adding `1` on the boundaries to indicate a count.

Gives you:

```js
{ "_id": true, "count": 1 },
```

You can be silly and expand that into a single document response using the [**$cond**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator to conditionally evaluate the field values:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "pollId": "hr4946-113" } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$vote",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "yesCount": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [ "_id", 1, 0 ]
            }
        },
        "noCount": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [ "_id", 0, 1 ]
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$project": { "_id": 0 } }
])
```

And the result:

```js
{ "yesCount": 1, "noCount": 0 }
```

Comment: How do I ensure im only counting those values that match pollId "hr4946-113"?

Comment: @john Filter like a normal query using `$match`. The changes here should make it very clear.

Comment: I had to leave this line out `{ "$project": { "_id": 0 } }` to make the second grouping work

Comment: @john No you didn't. It's a separate pipeline stage and all it does it omit the `_id` key which would then be equal to `null` from the overall result. There are people of high rep that you might be able to refute on this site. I am not one of them.

Comment: Thankss for the answer !, Worked for me although i've modified it.