# MongoDB: Count total number of true and false values for documents matching a query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework

My question is exactly same to this

> [MongoDB Count total number of true and false values for documents matching a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945060/mongodb-count-total-number-of-true-and-false-values-for-documents-matching-a-que)

I followed the same solution but I am not getting the desired output.

I have some products records in database. Some of them are free and some are not. I want to retrieve the count of free and non-free products. This is my records

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54abcdbeba070410146d6073"), "name" : "Product 1", "isFree" : true}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54afe32fec4444481b985711"), "name" : "Product 2", "isFree" : false}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54b66de68dde7a0c19be987b"), "name" : "Product 3", "isFree" : false}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54b66de68dde7a0c19bc897d"), "name" : "Product 4", "isFree" : false}
```

I am expecting output as:

```
{
   "free": 1,
   "nonFree": 3
}
```

This is my query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$isFree",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: null,
      free: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: ["_id",1,0]
        }
      },
      nonFree: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: ["_id",0,1]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

I am getting output as:

```
{
    "_id": null,
    "free": 2,
    "nonFree": 0
}
```

Comment: To refer to the value of a field, use a dollar sign, like `$_id`

Comment: You mean in the second `$group`? I also tried putting `$_id`. I am getting ouput as free:1 and nonFree:1

Comment: In the cond you put a literal `1`, is that not what you wanted?

Comment: I have added a question link that is exactly the same as my question. I followed that solution but I am not getting the desired output?

Comment: yeah, that answer doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip the first group, and use `$cond` to evaluate `isFree` directly:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: null,
      free: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: ["$isFree",1,0]
        }
      },
      nonFree: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: ["$isFree",0,1]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$project:{_id:0}}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gPabTDGp0kw)